# Optaplanner: work with multiple users submitting from multiple threads

Tags: optaplanner

I would like to know if we have a planning problem that can be used by many users at a single time. How we can handle this using optaplanner and get optimal solution for all the users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If every user (or group of users) have their own isolated `Solution` instance, that's called **multi-tenancy**. For example: a nurse scheduling web app which services multiple independent hospitals. The planning of 1 hospital (=tenant) does not affect the planning of other hospitals (=other tenants). Basically, every tenant gets their own `Solver` instance.

If **multiple users collaborate** on the same `Solution` instance, then there's only 1 `Solver` instance which solves that. Either all users have submitted their demands and wishes before `Solver.solve()` starts, or - in the case of real-time planning - they add/change their demands/wishes from a different thread with `Solver.addProblemFactChange()` while it's solving. For example: all nurses in a hospital submit their free off day requests before midnight. After midnight, the Solver schedules the hospital, taking those requests into account.

Neither of this is about **multi-threaded solving**, which is a different topic (but not related to users, so not relevant to your question).

Comment: Thank you for your reply first. I have a use case that many users are available on the same day and i have to organize an event using constraint that users availability should be more than 50%. We have a date range as input to organize the event. In this case if at the same time multiple users tried to find out the date of event on the base of same users availability. How we can handle this case using optaplanner?

Comment: One more query is related to create rules using a web interface is possible. If you can provide some sample related to this it would be nice.

Comment: Take a look at drools-wb and kie-wb to create rules with a web interface. For more info about that, ask on the drools mailing list (see drools.org).